# Labeled blocks in PL/pgSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-migration

This procedure run well in MySQL.

```
BEGIN

   some_name:BEGIN

   END

END
```

But **NOT** in PostgreSQL. It always show :

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "some_name" Line n...
```

How we do this in postgresql?
As an information, I'm working on project that was migrating a database from MySQL to PostgreSQL.

I don't know what is the best title for this case. Please someone edit the right title for appropriate with the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are not using nested procedures, but you are using nested blocks. These are supported in PostgreSQL well. There is different syntax for labels. It is described on first page of [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/plpgsql-structure.html) documentation. It is very practical to read it, because syntax of PL/pgSQL (PostgreSQL) is different than PSM (MySQL),

The correct syntax for labels in PostgreSQL PLpgSQL is `<<name>>`

So your code should to look like:

```
BEGIN
   <<some_name>>
   BEGIN
      ...
   END;
END;
```